# Name for categorical product inside a monoid

Tags: category-theory, monoid

If a monoid is a category with a single object, is there a "monoid-theoretical" concept that the categorical product translates to? As an analogue, in a poset the product translates to the notion of meet (and the coproduct to its dual, the join).

Just by unwinding the definition one can see that this boils down to the existence of two monoid elements $p_1$ and $p_2$ such that for every $x$ and $y$ in the monoid there's a unique element $\langle x,y \rangle$ that factors as $x = p_1\langle x,y \rangle$ and $y = p_2\langle x,y \rangle$; the question is whether the concept is a known and/or useful one.

Incidentally, if the monoid in question is a group then the existence of a product makes the whole thing collapse into the trivial group; this might or not hint that the concept I'm looking for is "too boring" to have a name. In fact it suffices for one of the projections to be right cancellable, or for the pair $\langle x,x\rangle$ to be left cancellable for some $x$, to make the whole thing collapse.

Comment: We can get nontrivial examples whenever we meet any object $A$ in a category which satisfies $A\times A\cong A$. Such is $\Bbb N$ (or any infinite set) in ${\bf Set}$, for example.

Comment: @Berci That's true, so the notion is not a degenerate one in the general case :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, for free monoids that's the longest common suffix.

Comment: Well, since it's arbitrary how you define the monoid operation as composition to the left or composition to the right (of functions), you can also get $x = \langle x, y \rangle s_1$ and $y = \langle x, y \rangle s_2$ as the analogue operation for the categorical product inside a monoid. With this latter definition, for free monoids the operation is the longest common prefix.

Comment: In either case, for free monoids the "coproduct" would be the "dual", i.e. if the "product" is the longest commons suffix, then the "coproduct" is the longest common prefix and vice-versa. Note however that I'm not saying here that a free monoid is isomorphic to its own square in terms of the actual categorical product.

Comment: For [non-free] monoids in general, the obvious notion to think of has to do with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup, but I'm unsure of the details.

Comment: Something I should have probably said yesterday: the catch with the categorical product is that it depends on the morphisms in the category, not just the sets. For example, $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \sim \mathbb{N}$ as sets by [Cantor pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) etc., but in the category of monoids, the free monoid on one generator is not isomorphic with the free monoid on two generators, this despite the fact that the sets they generate are isomorphic (as sets).

Comment: @RespawnedFluff (sorry for the late reply) for it to be a product, you'd have to choose $s_1$ and $s_2$ such that $x=\langle x,y\rangle s_1$ (and likewise for $y$) for _all_ $x$ and $y$ in the monoid; for the longest common prefix I think the $s$ would depend on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff A cancellative semigroup doesn't seem to be the thing either, at least prima facie; if one of the $s$ (say, $s_1$) is cancellable then we have that $\langle x,y\rangle s_1=\langle x,z\rangle$ implies $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,z\rangle$ which in turn implies $y=z$ and the monoid collapses to a point. If the $\langle x,y\rangle$ are cancellable, we can take $\langle x, x\rangle s_1=\langle x,x\rangle s_2$, which implies $s_1=s_2$, but then $x=\langle x,y\rangle  s_1=\langle x,y\rangle s_2=y$ and again the monoid collapses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know exactly one interesting thing to say about this, which is the following: as Berci says in the comments, this is equivalent to asking for objects $A$ in categories which are isomorphic to their cartesian squares $A^2$. There is a somewhat more general thing you could ask for, which is to ask for objects $M$ in monoidal categories which are isomorphic to their monoidal squares $M^{\otimes 2}$.

The fun theorem is that the free such thing (that is, the free monoidal category on an object equipped with an isomorphism to its monoidal square) has one nontrivial object whose endomorphisms are the [Thompson group F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups). This is due to [Fiore and Leinster](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508617).

Hence the Thompson group naturally acts by automorphisms on any object equipped with an isomorphism to its monoidal square (in any monoidal category whatsoever), and in particular there's a natural map from the Thompson group to any monoid satisfying your condition.

Comment: From reading Fiore and Leinster it sounds like the additional information that the monoidal product is the cartesian product gets you the Thompson group V.

Comment: That was some really fun reading; thanks! :) Learned quite a few new things. It also pointed me to the notion of a Jónsson-Tarski algebra, of which the question's setting seems to be a particular case (when the algebra's projection maps are mediated by monoid elements); this would seem to come close to the question's goal of finding some explicit "native" name for the gadget.

Comment: Jonsson-Tarski algebras seem to be pretty specific to sets. You can ask for objects isomorphic to their monoidal squares in much greater generality. Fiore and Leinster call them "idempotent objects."

Comment: Actually the whole idea of the question was to ask about the very specific case of products in a monoid as opposed to products in any general category, at the same elementary (or even introductory) level at which one recognizes the specific case of products in a poset as being equivalent to the "native" notion of a meet. In that view the definition of a JT algebra is too general rather than too specific for this purpose—the projections can be any arbitrary maps instead of being mediated by the action of two selected projection elements.

Comment: @askyle: I worry that you're mixing up objects and morphisms here. A Jonsson-Tarski algebra is (if I understand correctly) a set equipped with a bijection to its cartesian square. You can ask more generally for objects equipped with isomorphisms to their cartesian squares in some category. Your question concerns the special case where the category has one object. So the two concepts are incomparable, but objects equipped with isomorphisms to their cartesian squares generalize both (and objects equipped with isomorphisms to their monoidal squares further generalize both).

Comment: I'll try to work things out explicitly to see if I can spot where my mixup lies. In any category, we say that an object $P$ along with two arrows $p_1:P\to A$ and $p_2:P\to B$ is a product of $A$ and $B$ when for every pair of arrows $x:Q->A$ and $y:Q->B$ there's a unique arrow (let's call it $w_{x,y}:Q\to P)$) such that $p_1w_{x,y}=x$ and $p_2w_{x,y}=y$; moreover, it follows that every arrow $z:Q\to P$ can be represented as $z=w_{p_1z,p_2z}$.

Comment: (cont.) In the special case of a monoid (i.e. a category with a single object $*$, with the elements of the monoid being its endomorphisms), all the objects in question are the same—so the arrows $x:Q\to A$, $y:Q\to B$, and $w_{x,y}:Q\to P$ above become elements of the monoid, in which case we have a bijection between the underlying set of the monoid and its own (Cartesian) product, along with a pair of projection maps (given by the action of the projection elements), which I think is just what is meant by a JT algebra.

Comment: @askyle: if $A$ is any object in a category which is isomorphic to its cartesian square, then the monoid $\text{End}(A)$ is *also* isomorphic to its cartesian square, since $\text{Hom}(A, A \times A) \cong \text{Hom}(A, A) \times \text{Hom}(A, A)$ (and this should be an isomorphism of monoids, although I haven't checked this). In a general category, $\text{End}(A)$ being isomorphic to its cartesian square is a strictly weaker condition than $A$ being isomorphic to its cartesian square (and such an isomorphism should be the data of a Jonsson-Tarski algebra in a category with finite products).

Comment: It may be the case that a Jonsson-Tarski algebra in monoids turns out to be the same data as a Jonsson-Tarski algebra in a category with one object, but the thing we're calling the Jonsson-Tarski algebra is different in each case: in the first case it's the monoid, and in the second case it's the object whose endomorphisms are that monoid.