# Monoids as a category and product structures

Tags: category-theory

I'm currently going through  [these incredibly awesome lecture notes on category theory](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/4135/handouts/notes-2up.pdf) and I'm struggling to answer the question posed on page 26 (directly before Lecture 9). 
**Question:**  Characterize what it means for a monoid, regarded as a category, to have products. Can a finite monoid have products? I'm using **Definition 3** for products, on the bottom of page 22.
Suppose $(M, \times)$ is the monoid that defines the single-object category, I tend to call the object $\cdot$. A product structure will be the $4$-tuple $(\cdot, \pi_1, \pi_2, <-,->)$ where $\pi_1, \pi_2 \in M$ and for every $f_1,f_2 \in M$ I have some element $<f_1,f_2> \in M$ so that $\pi_i \times <f_1,f_2> = f_i$. 
I don't see how I could pick such $\pi_i$ unless $M=\{e\}$, in which case $\pi_i=<-,->=e.$ What other $M$ could this work for?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153736/name-for-categorical-product-inside-a-monoid